# loadUrl cannot be resolved even though WebView class has been imported

Tags: android, intellij-idea, webview

I'm making an app where a WebView fills the screen and will open a local HTML file.
For some reason, the loadUrl method won't resolve in the code below:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/fireinfo.html");
```

I'm using IntelliJ so it turns the loadUrl text to red and when I hover over it, all it says is "cannot resolve symbol 'loadUrl' ". I've imported WebView with:

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
```

I'm really new to this so I'm really not sure what else could be wrong, I'd appreciate any tips.

Comment: I had the issue that my acitivty name was the same asthe name of my webview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is in your onCreate method of the activity you need a setContentView

```
setContentView(R.layout.the_name_of_your_activity);

WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/fireinfo.html");
```

Comment: Ah! It wasn't in my onCreate method... that makes sense now, thank you so much!